# Laravel 5 route giving error "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and have declared a route that corresponds to a controller action but it gives an error of `"This webpage has a redirect loop"` and `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in case of ajax calls.

My route is:

```
Route::get('getsubcategories/{id}', 'HomeController@getsubcategories')
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Controller:

```
public function getsubcategories($id){
    return "abc";
}
```

I don't know where the problem resides. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you show us your routes file?

Comment: This is something specific to your app, I've just done a clean install of laravel 5, and used your route and controller code and visited /getsubcategories/234 and it returned 'abc'. Is there anything else in your routes.php?

Comment: Are you using middleware that uses redirects? Incorrectly setting it up is   the most likely reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Form Request, make sure you are not injecting the class in the constructor.

My mistake was this:

```
 public function __construct(SupplierFormRequest $supplier)
    {
        $this->supplier = $supplier;
    }
```

instead of injecting the interface there.